# RDD subtract dosen't work for user defined types

Tags: apache-spark

I tried this simple example

```
 scala> rdd2.collect
    res45: Array[Person] = Array(Person(Mary,28,New York), Person(Bill,17,Philadelphia), Person(Craig,34,Philadelphia), Person(Leah,26,Rochester))

    scala> rdd3.collect
    res44: Array[Person] = Array(Person(Mary,28,New York), Person(Bill,17,Philadelphia), Person(Craig,35,Philadelphia), Person(Leah,26,Rochester))

    scala> rdd2.subtract(rdd3).collect
    res46: Array[Person] = Array(Person(Mary,28,New York), Person(Leah,26,Rochester), Person(Bill,17,Philadelphia), Person(Craig,34,Philadelphia))
```

I expect `rdd2.subtract(rdd3).collect` only should be `Person(Craig,34,Philadelphia)` but I get rdd2 as my output Can anyone please explain this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the known issues with scala REPL where equality conditions dont work properly in REPL. try the following to fix it. This issue occurs only in the REPL and would go away when you are running he application via spark-submit.
This issue is explained in detail in this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2620).

```
scala> :paste -raw  // make sure you are using Scala 2.11 for the raw option to work.
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package mytest;
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, city: String);

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> import mytest.Person

scala> val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("Mary",28,"New York"), Person("Bill",17,"Philadelphia"), Person("Craig",34,"Philadelphia"), Person("Leah",26,"Rochester")))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[mytest.Person] = ParallelCollectionRDD[6] at parallelize at <console>:25


scala> val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Seq(Person("Mary",28,"New York"), Person("Bill",17,"Philadelphia"), Person("Craig",35,"Philadelphia"), Person("Leah",26,"Rochester")))
rdd3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[mytest.Person] = ParallelCollectionRDD[7] at parallelize at <console>:25

scala> rdd2.subtract(rdd3).collect
res1: Array[mytest.Person] = Array(Person(Craig,34,Philadelphia))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked well in my case. but how paste mode can solve the problem ?

Comment: the solution requires the case class to be under a package (mytest in the example). to make that happen we needed the paste mode. with raw option.